# Java - OutOfMemoryError during JSON String manipulation

Tags: java, java-memory-leaks

I am trying to track down a memory leak in the Java code shown below.

- This code throws `OutOfMemoryError: heap space` while running with a max heap size of 2 GB after handling only a few file updates.
- The compressed size of files on S3 are no larger than a few hundred kB.
- The input String ("amendment" variable) is no larger than 1 MB.
- A heap dump shows a `byte[]` of hundreds of MB in size - in one case it was taking up over 50% of heap space. (Tooling has not pointed to where this array is being created, however).

It uses an AmazonS3 client instance to read and write objects in a remote S3 bucket, and also uses Jackson's ObjectMapper for working with Strings and converting them to JSON etc. The Deflater and Inflater classes from the `java.util.zip` package are used for compression/decompression.

Is there an obvious memory leak in this code? Is there an obvious bug which could lead to an ever growing/huge byte array on the heap? I've been really scratching my head over this one for a while! Thanks.

```
class FileManager {
    // Constructor omitted
    private static final int BYTE_SIZE = 1024;
    private final String bucketName;
    private final AmazonS3 client;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void saveFile(String key, String amendment, String updateTimeStamp) throws Exception {
        S3Object object = null;
        try {
            JsonNode amendmentJson = objectMapper.readTree(amendment);
            ObjectNode targetJson;
            if (client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, key)) {
                object = client.getObject(bucketName, key);
                InputStream objectStream = object.getObjectContent();
                targetFile = (ObjectNode) decompress(objectStream);
                objectStream.close();
                object.close();
            } else {
                targetJson = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            }
            targetJson.set(updateTimeStamp, amendmentJson);
            byte[] contentBytes = compress(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(targetJson));
            try (ByteArrayInputStream contentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)) {
                client.putObject(bucketName, key, contentStream);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          // Logs and rethrows ...
        }
    }

    public byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
        deflater.setInput(data);
        deflater.finish();
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        deflater.end();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public JsonNode decompress(InputStream objectReader) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(objectReader);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        String outputString;
        inflater.setInput(data);
        try {
            while (!inflater.finished()) {
                int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outputString = new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
            log.info("Content not zipped");
            outputString = new String(data);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inflater.end();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(outputString);
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(reader);
        reader.close();
        return jsonNode;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which method of this class causes memory leak??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace you are getting.

Comment: [How to debug Java OutOfMemory exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512147/how-to-debug-java-outofmemory-exceptions)